# Git denies me access to push to remote github repository and returns incorrect username

Tags: git, github, ssh

Today I tried pushing to my github repository and got this error:

```
ERROR: Permission to victor126/simple-eth-wallet.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I then tried this on every single one of my repositories, and all gave me this error, which was really weird because yesterday I was able to successfully push. I then checked if my ssh key was in my ssh agent, and if the corresponding key was added on my github account. Both checked out.

What was even weirder was I then attempted to ssh to github with `ssh -T git@github.com` and this gave me:

```
Hi Abduboriy1/Networking! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

This is really weird because Abduboriy1/Networking is NOT my username. It's my friends username, but only the first part. We worked on a project together about a month ago.

Does anyone know what is going on here, and why it returns his username and not mine? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Use `ssh -Tv` or `ssh -Tvv` or `ssh -Tvvv` (add more v's until satisfied with the noise level of your debug output) to watch as your ssh tries keys. Think of your ssh as being provide a big key-ring full of keys. Without further instruction, ssh will just try *every* key *until one works* (and then stop trying because that key opened the lock). Meanwhile each "key" has a number stamped on it, and GitHub reads the key number once the key works and gets your user name from that key number. So if you have six keys that *could* work, the one that works *first* is "who you are".

Comment: The result is that you must carefully control *which* key or keys your ssh offers to GitHub. This has nothing to do with Git proper *unless* you specifically configure Git to invoke ssh with flags that control ssh's behavior (which you can do, but usually that's the wrong way to go about it: usually you want to control ssh's behavior with faked host names or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git set the default key to your friend's, check ~/.ssh/config and set the 'IdentityFile' to your own ssh key

Comment: Do you have any idea why git might have done this? Might there be any security breach since my friend's username is popping up? Or did I just give him my public key so I could get access to his repo? I'm confused why his username is popping up?

Comment: they may have set the git config in the repo to use their ssh key and it might've set it globally

Comment: *Git* does not do this. Git invokes ssh and pushes *all* the responsibility for authentication over *to* ssh, so everything from here on out is ssh's doing. You can configure `core.sshCommand` to add flags to your ssh invocation, or invoke a particular different ssh installation than the one you get by running `ssh` at the command line, but it's still ssh doing it. By default Git just runs ssh with no options.